# Error with Qt WebEngine : gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(642)] Switching to software compositing

Tags: qt, qml, qtwebengine

### Background

- Platform : windows 10
- Qt Version : 5.12.1

I have to port a QML application that was initially done with Qt 4.7.4, using QML QtWebKit.  This QML was pretty straightforward, it was just showing a local html.  I read [this web page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html) on how to migrate QtWebKit.

So, after a couple of hours try an errors, I decided to do this [qt example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webengine-minimal-example.html).

When I try to execute the application, I have this output :

```
[23912:5200:1125/182313.354:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(642)] Switching to software compositing.
[23912:5200:1125/182313.355:WARNING:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.
[23912:5836:1125/182313.911:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(583)] !GpuDataManagerImpl::GpuProcessStartAllowed()
[23912:5836:1125/182329.059:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(583)] !GpuDataManagerImpl::GpuProcessStartAllowed()
```

1. Any idea what I am doing wrong?
2. Would it be possible to stick with QtWebKit?
3. Is QtWebEngine is the best solution just to render a simple html user guide?

---

### My QtWebEngine Code:

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QTQml/QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QTWebEngine/qtwebengineglobal.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("QtExamples");
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QtWebEngine::initialize();
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/test/Resources/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

### Qt WebEngine QML

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtWebEngine 1.0

Window {
    width: 1024
    height: 750
    visible: true
    WebEngineView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "https://www.qt.io"
    }
}
```

---

### QtWebKit code

```
rootContext()->setContextProperty("uiDataLayer", pUiDataLayer);
setSource(QUrl("qrc:/SCmainWindow/Resources/userGuide.qml"));
QDeclarativeItem* item = qobject_cast<QDeclarativeItem*>(rootObject());
```

### QtWebKit Qml

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import QtWebEngine 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: userGuide
    width: uiDataLayer.getUserGuideWindowWidth();
    height: uiDataLayer.getUserGuideWindowHeight();

    Flickable {
        id: flickableWebView
        anchors.fill: userGuide;
        contentWidth: webView.width
        contentHeight: webView.height
        interactive: true
        clip: true

        WebEngineView {
            id: webView
            url : "file:///C:/SVN/products/faa_mx/vs2017.install2/install/MSVC10.0.x86.debug/lexix_verbyx/bin/win32/Lexis-UG-1.0-00.html";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @eyllanesc  Yes, the page is being rendered correctly.    Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Any idea what I am doing wrong?**

Those are not errors of Qt but of chromium that you must ignore them in many of the cases that in your particular case indicates that the application tries to use the GPU but for compatibility problems it will use the CPU (You should get those same errors if you run google chrome from the CMD and enable the flags to get the debug).

So obviate those errors since the code you provide is correct.

**Would it be possible to stick with QtWebKit?**

You can continue using Qt WebKit but there is no official support from Qt, you must compile it manually. The project is hosted in https://github.com/qtwebkit/qtwebkit.

**Is QtWebEngine is the best solution just to render a simple html user guide?**

The "best" is relative unless you indicate objective parameters that allow you to measure yourself in each technology / alternative. What I can point out to you is that it is the official option to render web pages, html, etc. that use HTML, js, etc.